# Granting full gcs bucket permissions to a GCP service account

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I want to create a GCP service account that will have full access to a specific bucket (say `my-bucket`).

I can work around this by providing to my service account the `roles.storageAdmin` role as follows:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create my-sa \
    --description="My Service Account" \
    --display-name="my-sa"
```

and

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
    --member="serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/storage.objectAdmin"
```

but unless I am wrong, this gives very broad permissions to all the project's buckets.

Is there a way to provide full access to a specific bucket (and only this one) to a service account?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`gsutil ch`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam#ch-examples) :

```
gsutil iam ch \
    serviceAccount:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectAdmin \
    gs://my-bucket
```

You can also get the IAM for your bucket :

```
gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket > iam.json
```

, modify it to add the bindings you want, and then set the IAM with the updated file :

```
gsutil iam set iam.json gs://my-bucket
```